# Posting a large amount of data to a web form from Excel VBA script

Tags: excel, vba, webforms

I'm trying to post a large volume of text into specific fields on a tax submission form.  In all, there are over 1000 fields.  The code I have works fine when testing a handful of entries.  But there are a couple thousand lines and when when I try to post all fields, Excel gives me an error stating "Procedure too large".  Now I am trying to clean up the code using variables.

Here is the original code:

```
Sub Fill_Form()

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate URL:="https://ritx-fl-cst2.bswa.net/(S(2kgryl5f1znhcqtjkb3tlvpb))/Schedule1.aspx"
    Do Until .readystate = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set txtSales1 = .document.all.Item("outerRep__ctl0_txtStateSales")
    txtSales1.Value = Sheets("cst").Range("e2").Value
    ...Code shortened for brevity but there are 548 of these in total...
    Set txtSales548 = 
    .document.all.Item("outerRep__ctl66_innerRep__ctl5_txtLocalSales")
    txtSales548.Value = Sheets("cst").Range("e549").Value


    End With
    End Sub
```

Since the project uses an Excel sheet, I want to post the values of certain cells into the tax website.  Specifically, E2 through E548, which are revenue fields and G2 through G548, which are tax collected fields.  Each of these rows is associated to a taxing jurisdiction and I have collected their associated form ID in columns D and F 2 through 548.

The code that I am trying to write
  1. Looks up the form ID in column D and posts the related value from column E
  2. Looks up the form ID in column F and posts the related value from column G

I think that variables for each portion of the lookup could be automated.  For example.

```
Set txtSales1 = .document.all.Item("outerRep__ct10_txtStateSales")
```

could be:

```
Dim SetTxt1 As String
Dim Counter1 As Integer
Dim SetTxt2 As String
Dim CellVSales As String
Dim SetTxt3 As String

SetTxt1 = "Set txtSales "
Counter1 = Counter1 + 1
SetTxt2 = "= .document.all.Item("""
CellVSales = E1 + 1
SetTxt3 = """)"
```

For the second line, txtSales1.Value = Sheets("cst").Range("e2").Value, it would have these settings:

```
Dim SetTxt4 As String
Dim Counter2 As Integer
Dim SetTxt5 As String
Dim CellVTax As String
Dim SetTxt6 As String

SetTxt4 = "txtSales"
Counter2 = Counter2 + 1
SetTxt5 = ".Value = Sheets(""cst"").Range("""
CellVTax = G1 + 1
SetTxt6 = """).Value"
```

This is where I am completely lost and have no idea where to start.  How do I combine the strings and also increment the cell value (e.g. E1 to E2 to E3, and so on)?

I envision the fist string would change from

```
Set txtSales1 = .document.all.Item("outerRep__ct10_txtStateSales")
```

to

```
SetTxt1,Counter1,SetTxt2,CellVSales,SetTxt3
```

and the second

```
txtSales1.Value = Sheets("cst").Range("e2").Value
```

to

```
SetTxt4,Counter2,SetTxt5,CellVTax,SetTxt6
```

Please tell me if I am way off base here.  I would absolutely appreciate any advise or assistance on how to accomplish this script.  Thank you so very much!

Comment: why are you using intermediate variables?  do not use `Set txtSales1 = .document.all.Item("outerRep__ctl0_txtStateSales")`
    `txtSales1.Value = Sheets("cst").Range("e2").Value`  ..... just use `.document.all.Item("outerRep__ctl0_txtStateSales").Value = Sheets("cst").Range("e2").Value`

Comment: can you put the field name list into a worksheet?

Comment: yes, I have 4 fields, 1) Field name for revenue, 2) value of revenue, 3) field name for taxes paid, and 4) value of taxes paid.  I've tried a bunch of ways to try and loop through the sheet, but I have zero skills.  Here's my current code, which does not work.  edit:  too long, i'll post it below

Comment: jeesh.  i can't paste the code.  too long

Comment: Dim SalesID As String
ID = Range("d1:d548")
Dim SalesVal As Integer
SalesVal = Range("e1:e548")
Dim TaxID As String
TaxID = Range("f1:f548")
Dim TaxVal As String
TaxVal = Range("g1:g548")

Comment: .document.getElementByID.Range (SalesID + 1)
Sheets("cst").Range(SalesVal + 1).Value

Comment: in your question, you said that you have over 1000 fields .... your code states that there are 548 .... i asked if you can put the fields into a worksheet ... fields like `outerRep__ctl0_txtStateSales`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per my earlier comment ...

try this ... you will have to edit your code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Fill_Form()

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL:="https://ritx-fl-cst2.bswa.net/(S(2kgryl5f1znhcqtjkb3tlvpb))/Schedule1.aspx"
        Do Until .readystate = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        With .document.all
            .Item("outerRep__ctl0_txtStateSales").Value = Sheets("cst").Range("e2").Value

                    '    ...Code shortened for brevity but there are 548 of these in total...

            .Item("outerRep__ctl66_innerRep__ctl5_txtLocalSales").Value = Sheets("cst").Range("e549").Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

'Procedure too large' means your code is too big for the VBA compiler to handle (the number here isn't that great). The only way to let the procedure run is to shorten it.

The code you pasted above seems to be painfully repeatable. First thing to do in my opinion would be to declare ranges you are working for and use a For Each loop.

If I understood right, your range goes row by row from E2 to E584. You can simply set it up as Rng variable by using:

```
Dim Rng as Range
Set Rng = Range("E2:E548")
```

Using .document.all.Item can be replaced by .document.getElementByID which usually works better to my knowledge.

For Each loop is explained here: http://www.homeandlearn.org/for_each.html

Finally, if you are working with the data from cells that are always situated in the same pattern for each of the cells, you could just use offset to get to them.

So, the for each loop within Rng would be setting up txtSales dynamically by taking the string from offsetting cell position and then just changing the value of the cell adapting the txtSales value.

Comment: WAR, thanks for the reply!  To follow up, can you tell me how to combine the strings into a single line?

Comment: There is a number of ways to do it, the choice depends on your needs. You can do it using regular Excel function called CONCATENATE, which is explained here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d
This would be best if your strings are contained within cells or are obtained during Excel calculations.

In VBA, you can use the & character which connects strings, e.g.
   str1 & "string"
You can also connect a variable, cell.value, etc. I suggest searching for 'Excel VBA string concatenate', that can answer few questions.